# Multi GPU usage with CUDA Thrust

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpgpu, thrust

I want to use my two graphic cards for calculation with CUDA Thrust.

I have two graphic cards. Running on single cards works well for both cards, even when I store two device_vectors in the std::vector.

If I use both cards at the same time, the first cycle in the loop works and causes no error. After the first run it causes an error, probably because the device pointer is not valid.

I am not sure what the exact problem is, or how to use both cards for calculation.

Minimal code sample:

```
std::vector<thrust::device_vector<float> > TEST() {
    std::vector<thrust::device_vector<float> > vRes;

    unsigned int iDeviceCount   = GetCudaDeviceCount();
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < iDeviceCount; i++) {
        checkCudaErrors(cudaSetDevice(i) ); 
        thrust::host_vector<float> hvConscience(1024);

                // first run works, runs afterwards cause errors ..
        vRes.push_back(hvConscience); // this push_back causes the error on exec

    }
    return vRes;
}
```

Error message on execution:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
what():  invalid argument
```

Comment: Are you using copy from host or use from host for the buffers?

Comment: Don't know what you mean exactly. This code copies from host to device.

Comment: So they are not in SLI mode?

Comment: No they are not in SLI. I was in hope, that SLI is not necessary, because calculation (in my case) could be asynchronous.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: What you are asking about is *completely* irrelevant. Please try and keep the signal to noise ratio up....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to perform a device to device of copy data between a pair of `device_vector` which reside in different GPU contexts (because of the `cudaSetDevice` call). What you have perhaps overlooked is that this sequence of operations:

```
thrust::host_vector<float> hvConscience(1024);
vRes.push_back(hvConscience);
```

is performing a *copy* from `hvConscience` at each loop iteration. The thrust backend is expecting that source and destination memory lie in the same GPU context. In this case they do not, thus the error.

What you probably want to do is work with a vector of *pointers* to `device_vector` instead, so something like:

```
typedef thrust::device_vector< float > vec;
typedef vec *p_vec;
std::vector< p_vec > vRes;

unsigned int iDeviceCount   = GetCudaDeviceCount();
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < iDeviceCount; i++) {
    cudaSetDevice(i); 
    p_vec hvConscience = new vec(1024);
    vRes.push_back(hvConscience);
}
```

[disclaimer: code written in browser, neither compiled nor tested, us at own risk]

This way you are only creating each vector once, in the correct GPU context, and then copy assigning a host pointer, which doesn't trigger any device side copies across memory spaces.

Comment: The reason it fails, I think, is that when push_back() is called the vector is resized.
This involves copying of device_vector that was already there to a new location.
Since that device_vector was created using GPU0, but now we are copying when GPU1 is active, we get an error.
I think that if you would call vRes.reserve(iDeviceCount) before the loop, there would be no problem.